# TFS Agent with Proxy configuration is Offline

Tags: tfs, proxy

I'm following the instructions on this page to setup an Agent behind a proxy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

Our proxy doesn't require a username/password so this is my config command:

```
config.cmd --proxyurl https://proxy.url:3128
```

I am able to go through the entire configuration and can see the Agent as "Running" in Services but the Agent is "Offline" in the actual TFS portal.

Any help always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons if a build agent is offline.

For the build agent is running as interactive mode, you need to start agent by running **run.cmd** file:

1. Open Command line as administrator
2. Run **run.cmd** file (under agent folder)

For the build agent is running as service, you can check whether the related service is running in Services.

In your case, you could first try to restart the **Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent** in services, and sine you run your agent as a service, also **restart the agent service** *VSTSAgent(machinename.xx)*.

If it's not work,  recommend you to do the reconfigure option, which may do the trick.

Comment: Also had the same issue but due to system date. I have to match the agent system date to server date.